# Is a comma appropriate in "Sounds good, thanks."

Tags: grammar, commas, semicolons, periods

If I am writing "Sounds good, thanks.", is a comma appropriate between "Sounds good" and "thanks"? It seems awkward/too much to instead do "Sounds good; thanks." or "Sounds good. Thanks."

Would the same rule as above apply for situations such as "OK, thanks." and "Yes, please."?

Comment: Use of the comma in this situation is appropriate. Use of the period is also appropriate, but also more formal.

Comment: I prefer the period, but I agree it is a style choice.  Both are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sounds good, thanks.
```

would only be used in informal contexts. It would not be appropriate in formal essay writing, for example, as `Sounds good` is a fragment. Thus, there aren't any rules per se.

Personally, I have observed a comma to be more commonly used. I also read commas as a short pause and periods as a longer stop, so `Sounds good. Thanks.` doesn't sound like I would say it. I know that is subjective, but as there is not a formal rule, I think it is appropriate.